# SSH from Windows PowerShell to Linux server fails to allocate Pseudo-Terminal; "stdin is not a terminal"

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, powershell, visual-studio-code

### Problem

I want to work on code projects on my linux droplet in digital ocean by loading the remote folder using Visual Studio Code's [remote SSH plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh).

In the interim, I'm trying to verify that powershell can connect to SSH so that I can then troubleshoot on VSCode.

### Background

- Client is Windows 10 Home
- Remote is Ubuntu 20.04
- ssh is at `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` and is in the path
- WSL on the same machine works fine with ssh to the remote machine

### SSH Setup and Issues

I have run these commands:

```
PS> Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
PS> Start-Service ssh-agent
PS> ssh-add C:\path\wsl\folder\private.key
Enter passphrase for C:\path\wsl\folder\private.key:
Identity added: C:\path\wsl\folder\private.key (myserver.com)
```

Running SSH generates a stream of Pseudo-terminal errors:

```
PS>  ssh me@myserver.com
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
...
```

Running ssh with `-T`, `-T -t`, and `-tt` yields the same result. This occurs on both powershell 5 and 6, regardless of administrator status.

I am not able to run any commands on the remote machine in this state, and there is no indication that a connection has been established.

### Question

How can I connect via ssh from my windows machine to my linux droplet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by adding `RequestTTY Yes` to the ssh config file. This file is stored at `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` by default on windows for [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

This is my current ssh config:

```
Host myserver.com
  HostName myserver.com
  User me
  RequestTTY Yes
```

This also resolved my problem with getting Visual Studio Code to load a remote coding project.